# String comparison failure in android when string import from a database

Tags: android

I'm a new one for android developing. I retrieved a string from hosted database. I want to compare that string and set it as a text according to comparison.

```
if((dataList.get(position).getname()).equals("5b275526bd5600499cce09ae")) {

            holder.txtTitle.setText("denim");

        }
        else {
            holder.txtTitle.setText("shirt");
        }

    }
```

The retrieved string is "5b275526bd5600499cce09ae". According to this settext should be "denim". But it display as "shirt".

Then I tried the following one

```
holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getname());
```

Then it dispayed as 5b275526bd5600499cce09ae". therefore there is no issues to be seen with the retriving value. I can't figure out with what wrong with this.

Please help me to figure out what's wrong with my code as I'm a new one for Android and Java.

Comment: print  `dataList.get(position).getname()` and check the value

Comment: use .equalsIgnoreCase("5b275526bd5600499cce09ae"); . may this help. java is case sensitive so its better to use equalIgnoreCase if we just wanted to compare spelling/chars.

Comment: I think there is no issue with the value, As I checked with holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getname()); as well. It will set the the value as 5b275526bd5600499cce09ae. And there is actually no errors with retrieval. Only issue is with the comparison

Comment: if(dataList.get(position).getname().equals("5b275526bd5600499cce09ae")) try this.

Comment: I tried all of the mentioned methods. But the issue is not fixed. I can't figure out what's wrong with that

Comment: if(dataList.get(position).getname().equals("5b275526bd5600499cce09ae")) tried?

Comment: Try to trim the value from the list: `dataList.get(position).getname().trim()`

Comment: Thank you all !! finally it worked.